# Jquery add class to div blocks before div block with specific class

Tags: jquery

I'm making a calender which needs to block previous days (before present day), months and years (there is 3 possible view ways).

I can get current date. Question is, **how could I add specific class to each div block which is appearing with value before current date (class "today").**

Take a look at the HTML structure:

```
<div class="days">
<div class="not-in-month day-button">31</div>
<div class="day-button">1</div>
<div class="day-button">2</div>
<div class="day-button">3</div>
<div class="day-button">4</div>
<div class="saturday day-button">5</div>
<div class="sunday day-button">6</div>
<div class="day-button">7</div>
<div class="day-button">8</div>
<div class="day-button">9</div>
<div class="selected today day-button">10</div>
<div class="day-button">11</div>
<div class="saturday day-button">12</div>
<div class="sunday day-button">13</div>
<div class="day-button">14</div>
<div class="day-button eventday">15</div>
<div class="day-button">16</div>
<div class="day-button">17</div>
<div class="day-button eventday">18</div>
<div class="saturday day-button">19</div>
<div class="sunday day-button">20</div>
<div class="day-button">21</div>
<div class="day-button">22</div>
<div class="day-button">23</div>
<div class="day-button">24</div>
<div class="day-button">25</div>
<div class="saturday day-button">26</div>
<div class="sunday day-button">27</div>
<div class="day-button">28</div>
<div class="day-button">29</div>
<div class="day-button">30</div>
<div class="not-in-month day-button">1</div>
<div class="not-in-month day-button">2</div>
<div class="not-in-month saturday day-button">3</div>
<div class="not-in-month sunday day-button">4</div>
<div class="not-in-month day-button">5</div>
<div class="not-in-month day-button">6</div>
<div class="not-in-month day-button">7</div>
<div class="not-in-month day-button">8</div>
<div class="not-in-month day-button">9</div>
<div class="not-in-month saturday day-button">10</div>
<div class="not-in-month sunday day-button">11</div>
</div>
```

This is structure for days. Months and years are similar to this.
As you can see today date is always marked with class "today" (10 April 2014).
Question is, what's the way to find all div blocks before div block with class "today" and add specific class to each one?

There could be different classes in div blocks before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use prevAll to get the previous siblings:

```
$( "div.today" ).prevAll().addClass('blocked');
```